# Regarding mysql where clause with empty string

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, sql-like

My query

```
SELECT order_id, order_item_id, product_id, date_due, ship_via 
    FROM order_shipment 
    WHERE (product_id LIKE 'PP80403396-502%%' AND ship_via != '');
```

OR

```
SELECT order_id, order_item_id, product_id, date_due, ship_via 
    FROM order_shipment 
    WHERE (product_id LIKE 'PP80403396-502%%' AND trim(ship_via) != '');
```

does not give me any results.

My expectation would be to display to display the results where ship_via field is NULL or is not empty.

Comment: Null and empty string are not the same thing. Add a check for null too (or use `coalesce`/`isnull` to check both at once).

Comment: do you get any error message?

Comment: Is there `coalesce` in `mysql`?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: @Bridge, thanks. Edited my answer ;-) I prefer `coalesce` over `ifnull`, but I didn't know `mysql` has one ;-)

Comment: Your where clause should be `WHERE (product_id LIKE 'PP80403396-502%%' AND (trim(ship_via) != '' or ship_via is null));`

Comment: @rs- Thanka a lot. This works. Nice and simple.

Comment: I was taking logic as following: I thought mysql would go through all the rows and skip over all the rows with empty strings and include the rest. Obviously there is a flaw. Thanks again for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULL` is not empty string and not not empty string. And the result of comparison is neither true, nor false, it's `NULL`. You should use `COALESCE` to test for `NULL` or empty. Or `OR`.

Comment: COALESCE will display first non-null result in the list. I need to display results where ship_via is null OR non-empty string.

Comment: `COALESCE(ship_via!='',TRUE)` ?